# Are form submissions the only way that an HTML webpage can send an HTTP request?

Tags: html, http

How many ways do HTML webpages provide to send an HTTP request?

Are form submissions in `<form>` elements the only way that am HTML webpage can send an HTTP request?

Comment: No, e.g. you can initiate a `GET` request using a hyperlink.

Comment: @Sebastian Thanks. Are these two the only ways to do that?

Comment: you could do it through Javascript (AJAX), is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following ways.

1. POST and GET using regular Form Submit

   ```
   <form method="GET/POST">

   </form>
   ```
2. GET using Hyperlink

   `<a href="something.html">Click here</a>`
3. POST, PUT, DELETE and GET using AJAX

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url : 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
     type : 'GET/POST/PUT/DELETE',
     data : data,  //For POST/PUT/Delete requests
     success : function(data) {

         //do response processing here
     }
   });
   ```
4. POST, PUT, DELETE and GET using XMLHttpRequest

GET::

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/server', true);

    xhr.onload = function () {
      // Request finished. Do processing here.
    };

    xhr.send(null);
    // xhr.send('string');
    // xhr.send(new Blob());
    // xhr.send(new Int8Array());
    // xhr.send({ form: 'data' });
    // xhr.send(document);
```

POST/PUT/DELETE ::

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST/PUT/DELETE", '/server', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
        // Request finished. Do processing here.
    }
    }
    xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum"); 
    // xhr.send('string'); 
    // xhr.send(new Blob()); 
    // xhr.send(new Int8Array()); 
    // xhr.send({ form: 'data' }); 
    // xhr.send(document);
```

Comment: you could make your answer more complete by mentioning the rest of HTTP requests (PUT, DELETE, UPDATE...)

Comment: Your answer isnt complete. There are other requests beside post and get in addition to sockets/etc.

Comment: This is why list questions are a poor fit for SO.

Comment: 3 and 4 are redundant.

Comment: @AndréDion 3 & 4 are different.......                XMLHttpRequest in the raw browser object that jQuery wraps into a more usable and simplified form and cross browser consistent functionality.......

jQuery.ajax is a general Ajax requester in jQuery that can do any type and content requests.

Comment: AJAX is a term (Asynchronous JavaScript + XML), XHR is an API in which to perform AJAX. jQuery has nothing to do with either.

Comment: I'd have to guess, but... because it's an incomplete answer to an inappropriate question?

Comment: @AndréDion, so  if Ajax is not related to Jquery, can you do Ajax request without importing Jquery library?

Comment: Absolutely. jQuery is just a JavaScript framework. The fact that you don't know the distinction means you probably should not be answering these types of questions.

Comment: Google either term. There are [plenty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) of [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)...

Comment: Kumar. Thank you so much! You've already had my upvote. May I also ask how each of the ways creates HTTP request? In other words, what does the HTTP request created by each way look like?

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what the HTTP requests they have created look like?

Comment: @Tim. They look like any other HTTP requests. Wouldn't you do better considering the HTTP spec, than considering how those requests are generated?